# Systemverilog unique array values during randomizatoin

Tags: system-verilog

I have a variable `logic [31:0] id` which is not declared as `rand` or `randc`. I need different ids each time into an array `logic [31:0] id_array [16]`.

```
logic [31:0] id;
logic [31:0] id_array [16];
foreach(id_array[i]) begin
    std::randomize(id);
    id_array[i] = id;
end
```

In the above code, there is a possibility of getting duplicate ids in the array. How do I change the code to get unique ids in the array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change this to

```
logic [31:0] id;
logic [31:0] id_array [$];
repeat (16) begin
  std::randomize(id) with {!(id inside {id_array});};
  id_array.push_back(id);;
end
```

or just

```
logic [31:0] id_array [15];

std::randomize(id_array) with {unique {id_array};};
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that the `unique` construct is only available in SystemVerilog 2012.  If you are using the 2005 version, then it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for randomization:

```
logic [31:0] id_array [$];
std::randomize(id_array) with { // random numbers in ascending order
  foreach(id_array[idx]) {
    (idx>0) -> id_array[idx] > id_array[idx-1];
  }
};
id_array.shuffle(); // randomize order
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option in case you haven't had enough...

```
logic [31:0] id_array [16];
std::randomize(id_array) with {
  foreach ( id_array[i] )
    foreach ( id_array[j] )
      if ( i!=j )
        id_array[i] != id_array[j];
}
```

BTW, @Tudor wrote a very nice [blog](http://blog.verificationgentleman.com/2014/07/the-not-so-comprehensive-guide-to.html) on SystemVerilog array constraints.  It's definitely worth reading.